# Collaborate With Chemistry.se?

Tags: feature-request

There is a significant overlap between physics and chemistry.

For example: [Explanation of "thermite vs ice" explosion](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/10320/explanation-of-thermite-vs-ice-explosion)

Therefore I suggest that questions tagged "chemistry" on physics.se be displayed and editable on both chemistry.se and physics.se. The reverse would also be beneficial: questions on chemistry.se tagged physics could appear here as well as there and be editable by both communities.

A question immediately arises, should we collaborate on other tags? I would suggest that only tags involving the word chemistry  or physics respectively should be cross-communal projects.

[edit]

There is a question on SO meta: [Asking on Multiple Sites: "Soft-Migration"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131950/asking-on-multiple-sites-soft-migration) which points out how it is mostly the sciences that would benefit from this feature. I guess that means it is "too specific," since we are relatively small. Democracy baby!

Comment: Sounds nice, but I suspect it would require major under-the-hood changes.

Comment: @dmckee Surely a "virtual stack" separate from both chemistry and physics could be created that would host said questions to allow cross-stack collaboration. That way edits could be visible in both communities without drastically modifying SE.

Comment: I don't know what the architecture looks like. At one point each site had their own database. Any way, I gave you my vote because the team likely won't respond unless there is a clear sign that this is desired.

Comment: This has been suggested many times on [metaSO], at least as far back as 2011 e.g. [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/117454). It looks unlikely to be implemented any time soon though.

Comment: I don't see a specific ***physics*** tag on Chemistry.SE. Could you link to some questions there which could overlap with Physics.SE?

Comment: @udiboy Good point! Tag searches for "electricity" and "magnetism" and other broad categories in physics turn up many promising candidates. It might need to be more of a collaborative sort of thing where someone flags a question as potential cross-stack material and a mod approves or rejects it. Also, people would certainly begin tagging things with "physics" on chem.se if they knew of this feature!

Comment: @udiboy We have [physical-chemistry] and [quantum-mechanics] over on Chem.

Answer (score 5):

As a moderator on both the sites involved, I sort of support this -- this was the reason I proposed [soft migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131950/asking-on-multiple-sites-soft-migration) in the first place. Note that soft migration is less complicated than your proposal -- we don't need editing and all, just that the posts should turn up on the main page and in searches. Allowing editing would probably be complicated in the implementation<sup>1</sup> as the privileges would need to get carried over.

I had already added a ticker chatroom feed for [physical-chemistry](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physical-chemistry) (and I just added one for [quantum-mechanics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantum-mechanics)) in the Phy.SE chatroom. If nobody has any objections I can convert it to a chat message feed (every new post is posted in the chatroom). It shouldn't cause too much clutter as Chem.SE doesn't have that much activity.

<sup>1. These things always *seem* easy to implement, but a large app like SE usually has complications in implementing such things. One great example is HTTPS -- to most, turning on HTTPS can be done with the flip of a switch. But for something like SE, [it's not so easy](http://nickcraver.com/blog/2013/04/23/stackoverflow-com-the-road-to-ssl/)</sup>

Comment: I don't think [physical-chemistry] overlaps a lot with physics, although [quantum-mechanics] might have some overlapping questions.

Comment: @udi You're right, QM has much more overlap that PC. But PC still has a fair amount of questions that are on topic for both,